# Is there any advantage to use the Mantra.js architecture framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, mantrajs

Meteor.js integrates well inside a Mantra.js architecture, but does it have advantages since it slows the running of my requests.
For instance a dummy request in GraphQL (get a random string from the server) runs in few ms using Apollo Client and 1 second and more using Mantra.js (exact same request wrapping Apollo stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only depends what kind of project you want to work on.

Mantra.js is an architecture framework for Meteor.js, that means :
it helps a developer to follow the creation and development of its modules corresponding to the Mantra framework. The developer is free to use any kind of front-end library he/she wants, any Data Query and Client caching he wants, but in my opinion, it doesn't really improve the quality of the code. Someone can organize a project with own rules and it can be maintainable easily.

So if your team is comfortable with your code structure you definitively don't need something like Mantra.js.